# Is it possible to select an int to be concated as a JOINed String?

Tags: mysql

I'm curious if it's possible to select, as one field a JOIN of several integral ids... something along the lines of

```
table foo
1 | a
2 | b
3 | c
```

and then pseudo code:

```
select CONCAT_AS_STRING( (select id from foo), ",");  //the "," would be the token that it would JOIN on
```

so the result would be 
"1,2,3"

Does MySQL have such a feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try GROUP_CONCAT:

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id SEPARATOR ',') FROM foo;